# What is the meaning of the web compartment in UWP?

Tags: uwp

The MSDN docs for UWP uri schemes differentiates `ms-appx` and `ms-appx-web` with this line:

> The ms-appx-web scheme accesses the same files as ms-appx, but in the
>   web compartment.

What is the web compartment and how does this impact the rest of the application? It seems a web view can only access content from this compartment - why is this?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the web compartment and how does this impact the rest of the application?

The short answer, it is by design. Loading local HTML resources is very much limited unless they are distributed along with the application. To load content from the your app package, use the `Navigate` method with a Uri that uses the [`ms-appx-web`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj655406(v=win.10)#ms_appx_web) scheme. For security reason, load html file from app package you must use `ms-appx-web`.

Just imagine, if html could use `ms-appx` to access local api without limit, you app will be unsafe. So, you could think `ms-appx-web` is accessed with security restrictions. And the official document also confirms this (**web compartment)**.

Comment: I gathered it was a security thing. Is there any documentation on what exactly the security restrictions are on the web compartment?

Comment: Currently, there are no related documents.